# Removing "Chapter 1" from the introduction chapter, but still have "Introduction" as heading for the chapter

Tags: chapters

I am writing my thesis, and for the Introduction chapter I wanted to remove the prefix "Chapter 1" from the chapter tilte while still having the header saying "Introduction". This is what I have right now
[image]

I have tried the code:

```
 \chapter*{Introduction}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
```

It removes "Chapter 1" from the chapter title, but it messes up the header and leave it blank.
How can I remove "Chapter 1" from this chapter, but still have "Introduction" as heading for the rest of the pages of this chapter?

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm using report documentclass

Edit2: Minimum working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is easy to obtain with `titleps`, a companion package of `titlesec`, but making it work also depends on your document class. Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code?

Comment: @Bernard, I added the code at my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a modification of [Bernard's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546594/119) to address the issue [where the chapter to be hidden is not the first one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546566/removing-chapter-1-from-the-introduction-chapter-but-still-have-introduction#comment1380776_546594).

The changes are:

1. Introducing a new boolean variable `haschapter` to test for whether the chapter number should be printed, to replace the check using `\ifthechapter`. The conditional header is written using this boolean toggle.
2. Incorporating the toggle into the chapter commands; so `\chapter` is overwritten to set the toggle to true, and a new command `\NHchapter` is defined to set the toggle to false while also setting the table of contents and the chapter mark.

Code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtoggle{haschapter}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
    \headrule
    \sethead{\iftoggle{haschapter}{\chaptername\ \thechapter\quad}{}\chaptertitle}{}{}%
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
    }%
\pagestyle{mine}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{\oldchapter{#1}\toggletrue{haschapter}}
\newcommand{\NHchapter}[1]{\oldchapter*{#1}\togglefalse{haschapter} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}\chaptermark{#1}}


\begin{document}

\NHchapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\newpage
\Blindtext
\chapter{A First Chapter}
\Blindtext

\newpage
\Blindtext
\NHchapter{Conclusion}
\Blindtext
\newpage
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `titlesec` + option `[pagestyles]`. Don't load fancyhdr in this case,as it will conflict with `titleps`.

*Unrelated*: needless to load `inputenc` as, sice 2018, the default input encoding for latex is `utf8`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
    \newpagestyle{mine}{%
    \headrule
    \sethead{\ifthechapter{\chaptername\ \thechapter\quad}{}\chaptertitle}{}{}%
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
    }%
    \pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
 \chaptermark{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\newpage
\Blindtext
\chapter{A First Chapter}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: tthat worked exactly as I wanted. However, when I added a Conclusion chapter to have the same layout as the Introduction, it didn't work. I just added  before the last line
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
\chaptermark{Conclusion}

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: Yes, I did compile twice.

Comment: I'll try to see whether there's a solution for this case  tomorrow (it's getting late here…), but I'm afraid it might require defining chapters formatting with `titlesec`.

Comment: I have tried to do this page style only for the specific chapters, by using  '\begingroup' and  '\endgroup'. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've been trying different thing and I got it to work exactly as I wanted. There are probably better solution to this, but I got it to work with my basic knowledge of Latex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\begingroup
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Introduction}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \chapter*{Introduction}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
    \Blindtext
    \endgroup
    \newpage
    \begingroup
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \chapter{A First Chapter}
    \Blindtext
    \endgroup
    \newpage
    \begingroup
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[L]{Conclusion}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \chapter*{Conclusion}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
    \Blindtext
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```